# Linking stylesheet to Django website on Apache

Tags: django, apache

I'm trying to get my Django website to use a stylesheet that until now worked just fine on a development server. As you can see below, I've been using the static files loader until now but no luck ever since I deployed it on Apache.

I'm hardcoding it now but that doesn't work either. I used `collectstatic` thus I should have all static files I need. I modified Apache config file to serve static files (I followed tutorial).

```
<!-- {% load static %}
<link href='{% static "stylesheet.css" %}' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>-->
<link href='var/www/html/site/static/stylesheet.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Any ideas?

*UPDATE:*  Config files and settings.py file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/pi/site.wsgi

ServerName 192.168.1.159
Alias /static /var/www/html/site/static/
Alias /static /var/www/html/site/media/txt/
Alias /static /var/www/html/site/media/photos/

<Directory /var/www/html/site/media/txt>
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html/site/media/photos>
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html/site/static>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html/site/>

Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Settings.py:

```
STATIC_ROOT = 'static/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
'/var/www/html/site/static/',
]
```

And in Apache.conf file I just added this to the end:

```
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/html/site
```

Changes made:

```
STATIC_ROOT = 'static/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
'/var/www/html/site/app/static',  #  this line modified to be more
]                                     #  clear
FILES_URL = '/media/txt/'
FILES_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/txt')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/photos/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/photos')
```

Changes made in site's config file on Apache:

```
ServerName 192.168.1.159
Alias /static /var/www/html/site/app/static/
Alias /files /var/www/html/site/media/txt/
Alias /media /var/www/html/site/media/photos/
```

And I'm using this loader to fetch it:

```
{% load static %}
<link href='{% static "stylesheet.css" %}' rel='stylesheet' 
type='text/css'>
```

When I type the path into terminal and hit Enter the stylesheet opens as expected.

Comment: Does the browser console show any issues when you load the page?

Comment: I checked the console too. It says 404 which means cannot be found. But it is there.

Comment: Okay. So does your stylesheet actually exist at the hardcoded location?

Comment: @ndmeiri  Yes, it is there. I wouldn't be posting on SO if I wouldn't have all the basics checked first.

Comment: If you tried these basic things, then you should have stated so in your initial question. I'm only trying to help. And I start by checking the basic things to save everyone time before investigating more complex potential causes.

Comment: @ndmeiri  I guess my comment came across wrong. I didn't mean it in a wrong way. I just checked the path in my terminal with `sudo nano` and it opened the correct file. I don't understand why Django can't see it.

Comment: No worries. Can you post any relevant Apache config files? And maybe the settings in `settings.py` relevant to static files?

Comment: I updated my question with requested details.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161336/discussion-between-ndmeiri-and-marky-mark).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your Apache configuration isn't quite right. You have three aliases for `/static` here:

```
Alias /static /var/www/html/site/static/
Alias /static /var/www/html/site/media/txt/
Alias /static /var/www/html/site/media/photos/
```

Each of these should point to a different alias, something like this:

```
Alias /static /var/www/html/site/static/
Alias /media /var/www/html/site/media/
```

I'm not 100% sure, but I'm guessing that `/static` is pointing to the last one you declare, `/var/www/html/site/media/photos/`. You can verify this by checking a file that exists under `/var/www/html/site/media/photos/` in the browser like this: http://yoursite/static/photo_that_exists.jpg

See here for more details: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files

Either way, you should only have one `Alias` definition per path. Give that a try.

Comment: I'm fiddling with it right now ... when the website is deployed is the static folder supposed to be in site's directory or in app's directory ? I guess it doesn't matter as much as long as the pointing path to it is correct.

Comment: I followed recommendation made by you and other fellow dev I chatted with yesterday and I studied the official docs about this problem. I made appropriate changes, but in console it still says "404 stylesheet.css" not found. I was screaming "Where are you looking for that stylesheet ???"

Answer (score 1):

As turned out ... All I needed to do is change `ServerName 192.168.1.159` to `ServerName 127.0.0.1` and static files loaded up like nothing.

Apparently Django in deployment needs to be pointed to 127.0.0.1 which is IP representation of 'localhost'. If I use my internal IP address Django loader for static files won't accept it.

I'd like to acknowledge @FlipperPA who pointed out at other bug I had which I would've otherwise missed. Thank you.

I don't think my understanding of this problem is correct so if you've got better explanation, please do share with me. Cheers.

Comment: It sounds like a networking issue. Are you running Apache on your local machine? It is probably worth reading through the `mod_wsgi` docs: http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/getting-started.html It take a little while to understand. Deploying Django isn't easy, so don't get frustrated, we've all been there!

Comment: Actually I don't find it that hard, it just takes little bit of practice on how the networking works. I'll delete it couple of times and deploy it again to get a hang of it. Cheers. Merry Xmas ....